# stored procedure for inserting values of tables into another tables with automatic identifier as FK PGadmin4

Tags: stored-procedures, foreign-keys, bulkinsert, pgadmin-4

I want to make an insert procedure for specific values of an table into another existing table.
The dificulty is that my excisting table has automatic identifiers as fk of another table.

When I insert them individually, I use a look up function. But now I don't known in PGadmin how to put this in a procedure. In oarcle I can use collections but in pgadmin I can't figure it out.

##### my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE public.field (field_id INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY
                                CONSTRAINT pk_veld_id PRIMARY KEY,
                                object_number INT,
                                experiment_number INT,
                                repetition INT, 
                                plants_field INT,
                                stem_field INT,
                                plants_square_meter numeric,
                                stem_square_meter_start numeric,
                                stem_square_meter_end numeric, 
                                date_extra_stem date,
                                row_number_field INT);

CREATE TABLE public.sticky_plates_fields (ID_sticky_plate INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY
                                    CONSTRAINT pk_sticky_plate_id PRIMARY KEY,
                                    sticky_plate_number INT,
                                    brand_sticky_plate varchar,
                                    version_plate numeric,
                                    field_id INT constraint fk_sticky_plates_fields references field );
ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public.sticky_plates_fields
    ADD CONSTRAINT sticky_plates_fields_unique UNIQUE (sticky_plate_number, field_id);


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS public.make_sticky_plate_counts CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE public.make_sticky_plate_counts (
            experiment_number INT,
            object_number INT,
            repetition INT,
            sticky_plate_number INT,
            brand_sticky_plate varchar,
            version_plate numeric, 
            date_start date,
            date_count date,
            species varchar,
            stage  varchar,
            count_species INT);
```

### look_up _function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION project.lookup_field_id
    (p_objectnumber INT,
     p_experimentnumber  INT, 
    p_repetition INT)
        RETURNS integer
        LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
        
AS 
$BODY$
DECLARE 
ln_field_id integer;
BEGIN
        SELECT field_id INTO ln_field_id
        FROM field
        WHERE p_objectnumber = object_number AND  p_experimentnumber = experiment_number AND p_repetition = repetition;
        RETURN ln_field_id;
END;
$BODY$;
```

### values:

```
insert into public.field(object_number,experiment_number,repetition,stem_field,stem_square_meter_start,stem_square_meter_end,date_extra_stem,row_number_field)
values (1,4072022,1,20,2.5,3.3,TO_DATE('1-04-2022','DD-MM-YYYY'),10);
insert into public.field(object_number,experiment_number,repetition,stem_field,stem_square_meter_start,stem_square_meter_end,date_extra_stem,row_number_field)
values (1,4072022,2,20,2.5,3.3,TO_DATE('1-04-2022','DD-MM-YYYY'),15);
insert into public.field(object_number,experiment_number,repetition,stem_field,stem_square_meter_start,stem_square_meter_end,date_extra_stem,row_number_field)
values (1,4072022,3,20,2.5,3.3,TO_DATE('1-04-2022','DD-MM-YYYY'),20);
insert into public.field(object_number,experiment_number,repetition,stem_field,stem_square_meter_start,stem_square_meter_end,date_extra_stem,row_number_field)
values (1,4072022,4,20,2.5,3.3,TO_DATE('1-04-2022','DD-MM-YYYY'),25);
insert into public.field(object_number,experiment_number,repetition,stem_field,stem_square_meter_start,stem_square_meter_end,date_extra_stem,row_number_field)
values (2,4072022,1,20,2.5,3.3,TO_DATE('1-04-2022','DD-MM-YYYY'),10);
insert into public.field(object_number,experiment_number,repetition,stem_field,stem_square_meter_start,stem_square_meter_end,date_extra_stem,row_number_field)
values (2,4072022,2,20,2.5,3.3,TO_DATE('1-04-2022','DD-MM-YYYY'),15);
insert into public.field(object_number,experiment_number,repetition,stem_field,stem_square_meter_start,stem_square_meter_end,date_extra_stem,row_number_field)
values (2,4072022,3,20,2.5,3.3,TO_DATE('1-04-2022','DD-MM-YYYY'),20);


insert into public.sticky_plates_fields(sticky_plate_number,brand_sticky_plate,version_plate,field_id)
values(2,'BIOBEST',3,project.lookup_field_id(1,4072022,2)); 
insert into public.sticky_plates_fields(sticky_plate_number,brand_sticky_plate,version_plate,field_id)
values(1,'BIOBEST',3,project.lookup_field_id(1,4072022,1)); 
insert into public.sticky_plates_fields(sticky_plate_number,brand_sticky_plate,version_plate,field_id)
values(3,'BIOBEST',3,project.lookup_field_id(1,4072022,3)); 
insert into public.sticky_plates_fields(sticky_plate_number,brand_sticky_plate,version_plate,field_id)
values(4,'BIOBEST',3,project.lookup_field_id(1,4072022,4)); 


insert into public.make_sticky_plate_counts(experiment_number,object_number,repetition,sticky_plate_number,brand_sticky_plate,version_plate,date_start,date_count,species,stage,count_species)
values(4072022,2,1,6,'BIOBEST',2.1,TO_DATE('1-04-2022','DD-MM-YYYY'),TO_DATE('14-04-2022','DD-MM-YYYY'),'WHITE_FLY_T','ADULT',12) ;
insert into public.make_sticky_plate_counts(experiment_number,object_number,repetition,sticky_plate_number,brand_sticky_plate,version_plate,date_start,date_count,species,stage,count_species)
values(4072022,2,2,7,'BIOBEST',2.1,TO_DATE('1-04-2022','DD-MM-YYYY'),TO_DATE('14-04-2022','DD-MM-YYYY'),'WHITE_FLY_T','ADULT',12) ;
insert into public.make_sticky_plate_counts(experiment_number,object_number,repetition,sticky_plate_number,brand_sticky_plate,version_plate,date_start,date_count,species,stage,count_species)
values(4072022,2,3,8,'BIOBEST',2.1,TO_DATE('1-04-2022','DD-MM-YYYY'),TO_DATE('14-04-2022','DD-MM-YYYY'),'WHITE_FLY_T','ADULT',12) ;
insert into public.make_sticky_plate_counts(experiment_number,object_number,repetition,sticky_plate_number,brand_sticky_plate,version_plate,date_start,date_count,species,stage,count_species)
values(4072022,2,4,9,'BIOBEST',2.1,TO_DATE('1-04-2022','DD-MM-YYYY'),TO_DATE('14-04-2022','DD-MM-YYYY'),'WHITE_FLY_T','ADULT',12) ;
```

---

### try out of stored procedure

Here I want some values of table make_sticky_plate_counts to insert into table sticky_plates_fields.
I don't know how I can make a procedure to insert the whole (distinct table) winto the sticky plate field table and using the look up function for finding the related FK integer.

````
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_records
    () LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    AS 
    $BODY$
    DECLARE
    p_object_number INT;
    p_experiment_number INT;
    p_r_epetitition INT;
    p_sticky_plate_number INT;
    p_brand_sticky_plate VARCHAR;
    p_version_plate VARCHAR;
    max_rownumbers_insert INT := 0;
    
BEGIN
        max_rownumbers_insert :=  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT object_number,experiment_number,repetition FROM make_sticky_plate_counts) as temp;
        FOR i IN 1..max_rownumbers_insert
            LOOP
                p_object_number := SELECT object_number [i] FROM (SELECT DISTINCT object_number,experiment_number,repetition FROM make_sticky_plate_counts) as temp  ;
                p_experiment_number := SELECT experiment_number [i] FROM (SELECT DISTINCT object_number,experiment_number,repetition FROM make_sticky_plate_counts) as temp  ;
                p_repetitition:= SELECT repetitition [i] FROM (SELECT DISTINCT object_number,experiment_number,repetition FROM make_sticky_plate_counts) as temp ;
                p_sticky_plate_number:=SELECT sticky_plate_number [i] FROM (SELECT DISTINCT object_number,experiment_number,repetition FROM make_sticky_plate_counts) as temp);
                p_brand_sticky_plate :=SELECT brand_sticky_plate [i] FROM (SELECT DISTINCT object_number,experiment_number,repetition FROM make_sticky_plate_counts) as temp);
                p_version_plate :=SELECT version_plate [i] FROM (SELECT DISTINCT object_number,experiment_number,repetition FROM make_sticky_plate_counts) as temp);
                
                INSERT INTO sticky_plate_fields(field_id, sticky_plate_number, brand_sticky_plate,version_plate)
                VALUES (project.lookup_field_id(p_object_number,p_experiment_number,p_repetition),p_sticky_plate_number,p_brand_sticky_plate,p_version_plate);
      
            END LOOP; ```
````

Answer (score 0):

I could figure it out. Maybe it is helpfull for someone else:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_records
    () LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    AS 
    $BODY$
    DECLARE
    curs cursor for select * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT object_number,experiment_number,repetition,sticky_plate_number,brand_sticky_plate,version_plate FROM make_sticky_plate_counts) as temp;
    
BEGIN
        FOR row IN curs LOOP
        INSERT INTO sticky_plates_fields(field_id, sticky_plate_number, brand_sticky_plate,version_plate)
        VALUES (project.lookup_field_id(row.object_number,row.experiment_number,row.repetition),row.sticky_plate_number,row.brand_sticky_plate,row.version_plate);
        END LOOP;

END ;
$BODY$;
```